# Run function after audio is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I want to run a function after checking if an audio file is downloaded.

My js:

```js
// https://freesound.org/people/jefftbyrd/sounds/486445/
var audioFile = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hitoribot/my-room/master/audio/test/test.mp3";

var audioElem = document.querySelector("audio");
var startElem = document.querySelector("button");
var resultScreen = document.querySelector("p");

function checkAudio() {
    audioElem.setAttribute("src", audioFile);
    if (audioElem.complete) {
        resultScreen.innerHTML = "loaded audio";
        }
    }

startElem.addEventListener("click", function(){
    checkAudio();
});
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/carpenumidium/pen/KKPjRLR?editors=0011

I want the "loaded audio" text to be displayed, after the audio file has completed downloading. The code to check if the file has completed downloading might be utter bs so please go easy on me.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @R.Duteil this may not fit in the setAttribute space. As even when the src attribute is set its possible the the media file is not loaded for the browser to play till the end because that might be quite bulky..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the correct even to check the loaded status. See below a snippet that will do that.

You need to use the `canplaythrough` event that means

> The browser estimates it can play the media up to its end without
>   stopping for content buffering.

The event you are using `complete` is actually triggered when

> The rendering of an OfflineAudioContext is terminated.

```js
// https://freesound.org/people/jefftbyrd/sounds/486445/
var audioFile = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hitoribot/my-room/master/audio/test/test.mp3";

var audioElem = document.querySelector("audio");
var startElem = document.querySelector("button");
var resultScreen = document.querySelector("p");

function checkAudio() {
  audioElem.setAttribute("src", audioFile);
  audioElem.addEventListener('canplaythrough', (event) => {
    resultScreen.innerHTML = "loaded audio";
  });
}

startElem.addEventListener("click", function() {
  checkAudio();
});
```

```html
<audio controls="controls" src=""></audio>

<button>load audio</button>

<div class="result">
  <h1>Audio file status:</h1>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

For more on audio elements refer [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: First time I'm hearing of the canplaythrough event, so I learned many new things today.Thanks Manish!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `onload` event to get notified when *the full* audio is loaded:

```js
function checkAudio() {
    audioElem.setAttribute("src", audioFile);
    audioElem.onload= ()=>{
        resultScreen.innerHTML = "loaded audio";
    }
}

startElem.addEventListener("click", function(){
    checkAudio();
});
```

Comment: This wasn't working for me, due to most probably my ignorance. I selected Manish's answer because it worked and was suitable for my use. Still, thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Fzs this wont work as the `onload` event is not available with audio element

Comment: @Manish Yes, I see now. Your answer is also much better explained, +1. And I learned something new: not all *loadable* HTML elements have *onload* event...