# run 2 html video side by side at the same time JS

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I would like to play 2 html video exactly at the same time (side-by-side).

I made a button which has a `click` EventListener on it. This listener trigger the 2 `<video>` tag to play it, but I think there is `150 ms` a delay at the second `play` trigger.

**index.html**

```
<section>
    <video src="source1" id="video1"></video>
    <video src="source2" id="video2"></video>
    <button id="play">Play</button>
</section>
```

and here is the basic **script.js** file.

```
    const $video1 = document.getElementById('video1');
    const $video2 = document.getElementById('video2');
    const $play = document.getElementById('play');

    const playVideo = () => {
        $video1.play();
        $video2.play();
    };

    $play.addEventListener('click', playVideo);
```

These 2 videos are almost the same, except the first video size is about **12MB** and the other one is around **20MB**

**What I tried:**

Tried to add a `console.time('video')` that could logs the delay between each `play` function call, but that can be different in each environment.

Comment: This might be a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46254716/javascript-how-can-i-play-multiple-videos-at-once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Both of the answers was correct.
What I didn't know, that one of the video file has sound, and the other don't. That caused the 150ms delay.

Solved it with `ffmpeg`. Create an `.mp3` file with the sound (and play it with `<audio>`), and 2 `.mp4` files without sound.
They are playing exactly at the same time now.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I'm aware of about playing video in sync is to emit a custom event to sync the video in requestAnimationFrame:

```js
var videos = {
    a: Popcorn("#a"),
    b: Popcorn("#b"),
  },
  scrub = $("#scrub"),
  loadCount = 0,
  events = "play pause timeupdate seeking".split(/\s+/g);

// iterate both media sources
Popcorn.forEach(videos, function(media, type) {

  // when each is ready... 
  media.on("canplayall", function() {

    // trigger a custom "sync" event
    this.emit("sync");

    // set the max value of the "scrubber"
    scrub.attr("max", this.duration());

    // Listen for the custom sync event...    
  }).on("sync", function() {

    // Once both items are loaded, sync events
    if (++loadCount == 2) {

      // Iterate all events and trigger them on the video B
      // whenever they occur on the video A
      events.forEach(function(event) {

        videos.a.on(event, function() {

          // Avoid overkill events, trigger timeupdate manually
          if (event === "timeupdate") {

            if (!this.media.paused) {
              return;
            }
            videos.b.emit("timeupdate");

            // update scrubber
            scrub.val(this.currentTime());

            return;
          }

          if (event === "seeking") {
            videos.b.currentTime(this.currentTime());
          }

          if (event === "play" || event === "pause") {
            videos.b[event]();
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
});

scrub.bind("change", function() {
  var val = this.value;
  videos.a.currentTime(val);
  videos.b.currentTime(val);
});

// With requestAnimationFrame, we can ensure that as 
// frequently as the browser would allow, 
// the video is resync'ed.
function sync() {
  if (videos.b.media.readyState === 4) {
    videos.b.currentTime(
      videos.a.currentTime()
    );
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(sync);
}

sync();
```

```css
html{font-family:arial;}
```

```html
<script src="https://static.bocoup.com/js/popcorn.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video height="180" width="300" id="a" controls> 
<source src="https://videos.mozilla.org/serv/webmademovies/popcorntest.mp4"></source>
<source src="https://videos.mozilla.org/serv/webmademovies/popcorntest.ogv"></source>
<source src="https://videos.mozilla.org/serv/webmademovies/popcorntest.webm"></source>
</video>
<video height="180" width="300" id="b"> 
<source src="https://videos.mozilla.org/serv/webmademovies/popcorntest.mp4"></source>
<source src="https://videos.mozilla.org/serv/webmademovies/popcorntest.ogv"></source>
<source src="https://videos.mozilla.org/serv/webmademovies/popcorntest.webm"></source>
</video>

<input type="range" value="0" id="scrub" />
```

**Ref:** https://bocoup.com/blog/html5-video-synchronizing-playback-of-two-videos

Answer (score 1):

I will also add this link here, as evident someone had a very similar problem, albeit with audio

[Run function after audio is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58180304/run-function-after-audio-is-loaded)

It appears you are looking for this event listener "canplaythrough", check more in the link.

```
function checkAudio() {
  audioElem.setAttribute("src", audioFile);
  audioElem.addEventListener('canplaythrough', (event) => {
    resultScreen.innerHTML = "loaded audio";
  });
}
```